# How would I set attributes of a method within a class?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

In a Python/Qt program, i want to notify the user when a monitored value is outside the expected range. To avoid false positives, the value should be outside the range several times in a row, and we should only notify the user once so it can be acted upon or dismissed.

Below would be my approach, but I am accumulating way too many class attributes that are only used in a single function.  What is a cleaner way to implement this?

Is there a way for _counter and _enabled to attributes of the method check_value() only instead of the class TestScreen()?

```
class TestScreen(QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    self._counter = 0
    self._enabled = True

  def check_value(self):
    if self._enabled:
        # don't act on the first out of bounds value
        if value > target_value:
            self._counter += 1

        # notify the user when multiple out of bounds values measured
        # only notify once
        if self._counter > 5:
            self._counter = 0
            self._enabled = False
            QMessageBox.Error("Value too high")
```

Comment: I personally see no issues with this code, I also don't think that there is any reasonable way to make this cleaner, it is also kinda hard to understand what exactly You want since the `value` can be higher than `target_value` for about 5 times before it gets stopped

Comment: as for me your code is correct way to do this. And all your ideas for changing `_counter` and `_enabled` makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Because _counter and _enabled are only used in the method check_value, I was hoping there was a way to make them specific to that method.  If I add other methods that require unique counters, my attributes start getting very cluttered.
@Matiss you are correct: I should be checking value differently